# SNMP configuration - black list external hard drives

Tags: redhat, snmp

Is there a way on a RHEL server to blacklist external hard drives from SNMP configuration so that if and external HD fills up, SNMP doesn't 'detect' it.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on your SNMP daemon (and which MIB you're using).

If you're using net-snmp and the Host Resources MIB: **No**.
Host Resources polls all attached storage devices - there's no way I'm aware of to change its list.

If you're using net-snmp and the `disk` configuration directive: **Yes**.
Simply don't list drives you don't want to poll.

If you're using some other SNMP daemon: You're on your own :-)